# React Modal Component

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I have a react app that displays a modal component.  The problem I'm running into is that I want the modal to confirm that the user wants to post the elements of v the form to an api.  The form takes 1/4 of the right hand portion of the screen.. I want the modal to display in the middle of the screen.

I an call the modal component in the middle of the screen bit then I lose access to tje form data..

What are best practices to deal with this situation?

Thanks in advance@
Chris

```
import React from 'react'
import "./Modal.css";
import boxes from  "../../assets/boxes.svg";
import logo from "../../assets/logo.svg";

export const Modal = () => {
  return (
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="background">
                <h4 class="margin-bottom">Saving to Master</h4>
                <h3 class="margin-top">Confirming Your Booking</h3>
                <img src={logo} alt="logo image"/>
                <h2 class="reduce-text">Save and Submit Timeslot</h2>
                <h2>for <span class="bold underline">John</span></h2>
                <div><h1> REF81356</h1></div>
                <img src={boxes} alt="Two Double Boxes"/>
                <br/>
                <button class="btn-close">Close</button>
                <button class="btn-submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Could you plz share your modal component's code here? Without checking it is difficult to understand. Thanks.

Comment: I've attached the Modal component code and the code I am calling it from.  I want the Modal to be displayed on the center of the screen, while using the form to submit it to a post api.  I'm working on someone elses code base here, so ignore how messy the axios calls are, Im working on it :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the modal code. Modal displays in center.``` I lose access to tje form data``` Could you explain this?

Comment: Sure!  The form is in a component called sidebar.js.  sidebar.js takes up 1/4 of the screen.  When I bring the modal component into the sidebar... it fills the component width.  I'd like to display in the center of the screen outside the bounds of the component.   How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the modal from a sidebar button that is 1/4 of the parent component then declare the modal component in the parent and from a button in the sidebar display the modal.
Plz, take a look at this [modal lik](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/components/modal/). It may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  The problem is, on the modal, I need to submit data back to an api with a post.  If I call the component on a component in the middle of the screen, that component doesn't have the data from the form.

Comment: Hey thanks I got it with the help from that link!